# React array lookup not reading variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display an entry from and array of objects. If I hardcode the array position with an integer it displays the correct value. If I replace the array position with a state variable it becomes undefined. I can display the variable on the webpage and using javascript have proven it's a number. When I use variable it says "Cannot read property of undefined" I know it is defined because I can view number on page.

I have changed the variable to an integer and it works correctly. I have displayed the variable on the page and that is correct and in range of the array. I have also confirmed using javascript that the variable is indeed a nummber.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const Quiz = ({ myKanji }) => {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState(myKanji);
  const [quizKanji, setQuizKanji] = useState([]);
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("*");
  const kanjiClick = (id) => {
    console.log("KC" + answer["id"]);
    if (id === answer["id"]) {
      alert(true);
    }
  };
  const findKanji = () => {
    let newKanji = [];
    while (newKanji.length < 2) {
      let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
      if (newKanji.indexOf(x) === -1) {
        newKanji.push(x);
      }
    }
    //console.log("--" + newKanji);
    return newKanji;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log("aaa");
    let y = findKanji();
    setAnswer(Math.floor(Math.random() * y.length));
    //console.log(`loc ${ansLoc} ans ${answer}`);
    /*
    console.log("MK" + myData);
    console.log("y" + y);
    let z = Math.floor(Math.random() * y.length);
    console.log("answer " + z);
    setAnswer(y[z]);
    //setAnswer(kanjiList[Math.floor(Math.random() * (y.length + 1))]);
    console.log("bbb" + JSON.stringify(answer));
    */
    setQuizKanji(y);
    console.log("+++" + y);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Quizes</h1>
      <h3>
        {myKanji[answer]["translation"]}--{answer}
      </h3>
      {quizKanji.map((kanji) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p onClick={() => kanjiClick(myKanji[kanji - 1]["id"])}>
              {myKanji[kanji - 1]["kanji"]}
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the data being passed as variable "myKanji":

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    kanji: "赤",
    word: "akai",
    translation: "red",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    kanji: "青",
    word: "aoi",
    translation: "blue",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    kanji: "みどり",
    word: "midori",
    translation: "green",
  },
];
```

This is really confusing me so please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear which variable is meant to be used for the index. Also include the full error message; the one you've included _"Cannot read property of undefined"_ is truncated

Comment: sorry Phil, I realize I did not have the code with variable. It is in the h3 tag I have made edit to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are setting the answer as an integer in the `useEffect`

```
    setAnswer(Math.floor(Math.random() * y.length));
```

and you are trying to compare `answer['id']` in `kanjiClick` method.

```
  const kanjiClick = (id) => {
    console.log("KC" + answer["id"]);
    if (id === answer["id"]) {
      alert(true);
    }
  };
```

Remove the ['id'] and keep only `answer`
like this

```
  const kanjiClick = (id) => {
    console.log("KC" + answer);
    if (id === answer) {
      alert(true);
    }
  };
```

Set the answer default value as 0 so you won't get an error for `{myKanji[answer]["translation"]}--{answer}` when the page loads.

```
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(0);
```

Comment: Comparing `id` properties would be safer than indexes

Comment: Hi Phill I'm not saying to compare the index, he is setting the answer as a random integer and trying to get the answer["id"] which is the problem.
I answered what he asked for `undefined` issue

Comment: Thanks for response. Right now the issue is I am trying to display the "translation" of "myKanji" at position "answer". I am updating <h3> tag to reflect how code should work.

Comment: Hey Leo the issue you said is `undefined` it will be solved if you try my suggested answer. If you have another doubt or question please open a new question don't just edit in the same

Comment: I do realize what you are saying. I do want "answer" to be an integer. The code that comes back as undefined is "{myKanji["answer"]["translation"]}" in the h3 heading. It is supposed to show "myKanji"'s position so it needs to be a number. When I hard code a number like this. "{myKanji[0]["translation"]}" it displays the proper translation no error. sorry had to add quotes to answer because stackoverflow was changing what I typed. I have correct code edited above in my post.

Comment: Hii @leo check the answer I updated it